# fix my code to work with disabling buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

how do I disable all the buy buttons by attaching them to if statements(for example for the first buy button)

```
if counter.get()>15:
 state="disabled
else:
 state="enabled"
```

I have tried like 20-50 different things even changing my whole code to grid style. i just want the code i have and a simple way to disable buttons until a condition is met. having the hardest time figuring this out.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("480x320")
root.title("Button Clicker")

counter = tkinter.IntVar()
Ant = tkinter.IntVar()
autoclicker = 0

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

def buyAnt(event=None):
    if counter.get()-10>=0:
        counter.set(counter.get() -10) ,Ant.set(Ant.get() + 1)

def buyCat(event=None):
    if counter.get()-50>=0:
        counter.set(counter.get() -50)

def buyDog(event=None):
    if counter.get()-100>=0:
        counter.set(counter.get() -100)

def buyVillager(event=None):
    if counter.get()-200>=0:
        counter.set(counter.get() -200)

def autoclick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get()+1)
    root.after(1000, autoclick )

def buyAutoClicker(event=None):
    if counter.get()-15>=0:
        counter.set(counter.get() -15), autoclicker + 1, 
            root.after(1000, autoclick)


tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=Ant).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="Click", command=onClick, fg="dark green", 
    bg = "white").pack()

btn2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Buy AutoClicker", 
    command=buyAutoClicker, fg="dark green", bg = "white").pack()

tkinter.Button(root, text="Buy Cat", command=buyCat, fg="dark green", 
    bg = "white").pack()

tkinter.Button(root, text="Buy Dog", command=buyDog, fg="dark green", 
    bg = "white").pack()

tkinter.Button(root, text="Buy Villager", command=buyVillager, 
    fg="dark green", bg = "white").pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I expect click(normal) Buy AutoClicker(greyed out until counter>15)

Comment: thanks for the help with that part    def Rebirth(event=None):
                                                            if counter.get()-10>=0:
                                                               counter.set(0), rebirth+1, autoclicker.set(0)           how would i make it if a button is pressed the counter would revert to zero and the autoclicker would stop auto clicking. i have it reverting to zero but cant figure out why my auto increase of counter is still going off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `configure` method lets you change the options of a widget, and the available parameters depend on the widget you're configuring. State of a widget is changeable by calling the state parameter and setting its values as "normal" or "disabled": `wdiget.configure(state = 'disabled')`.

First problem you have with your code is that you have deleted the only reference to your button widget you want to change the state of. This can be solved by splitting `.pack()` method to a new line:

```
btn2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Buy AutoClicker", 
    command=buyAutoClicker, fg="dark green", bg = "white", state = 'disabled') # also you might consider setting the initial state of the button to 'disable'
btn2.pack() # note here
```

As for checking the value of counter and updating buttons state, this can be done by attaching a callback function to tkinters `IntVar()` and catching it when it changes:

```
...

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

def callback(name, index, op):
    print("called")
    if counter.get() < 15:
        btn2.configure(state = 'disabled')
    else:
        btn2.configure(state = 'normal')

counter.trace("w", callback)

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=Ant).pack()

...
```

This will keep your button "Buy AutoClicker" disabled while counter is less then 15. If you want multiple buttons to be disabled at the same time, you're gonna need to create a list.

Comment: thanks. this is like my first experience with making a game. im learning unity on the side so when i have my real idle game planed up i can put it on a browser game website/ app store.